# How to not do in-line editing

Tags: support, editing, rollbacks

I recently gained the privilege of in-line edits, but I am trying to access the old screen with more options where you could rollback. Any help?

Side note: There is a user who repeatedly edits a post, and instead of improving it, just makes it worse. Any way to report?

Comment: `http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/<postid>/edit` takes you to the full edit page. But one can only roll back from the revisions page. As for the last question, what about a flag? It may however be better to try to resolve the matter via comments first, depends on the situation.

Comment: @DanielFischer Ok, I would suggest a rollback feature be made for inline edits then.

Comment: @DanielFischer I am not sure I understand correctly what you mean to say, but one *can* rollback from the full-page, there is a dropdown to select the revision, then one saves it.

Comment: Why do you want that feature there? It seems much less convenient to me than doing the rollback via the revisions page.

Comment: @quid Well, I never noticed that. Learn something new every year.

Comment: Whenever I click edit it's always the inline editor and I have to click into the revisions page to rollback.

Comment: Why do you click edit in the first place? Why don't you click into the revisons page right away when you want to do a rollback?

Comment: How? ...................

Comment: It is the link in the center of a post saying when the post was last edited. Note it is is only present when there are earlier revisions but if you want to rollback it must be there.

Comment: Ok, I see it now. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

As Daniel Fischer explained you can 'manually' go to the full-edit page by accessing `http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/<postid>/edit`

Another way to get to the full-edit page is via the revisions page of the post and selecting "edit" there in the header of the most recent revision (or also the revision which one wants to with).

However, if the goal is to perform a rollback there is no need for the full-edits page for a user that has the editing privilege. On the *revisions page* one can just select "rollback" in the header of *on the old revision* to which one wants to rollback the post (the option is not present in the header of the most recent revision).

The revisions page is the page one gets to when following the link in the middle of a post saying "last edited {some time}."  If there has not been any edit to the post, this link is not there yet one can still access the page 'manually' under `http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/<postid>/revisions`

To recap, to do a rollback when having editing privilege click the link in the middle of the post and select "rollback" on the relevant revision directly.